# dpkg: symbol lookup error: dpkg: undefined symbol: setexecfilecon

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I am getting this error:

```
dpkg: symbol lookup error: dpkg: undefined symbol: setexecfilecon
```

When attempting to run `dpkg` or `apt-get install -f` to resolve dependency issues.  The problem is that without dpkg working, I'm kind of stuck. I know my packages are a bit of a mess, stuck between two versions of Ubuntu. But I can't resolve them without the ability to install/update packages.

Comment: what version of ubuntu please?

Comment: 14.04. However, the package discrepancies are with 19.04. Some packages were installed manually that created the discrepancies, and I'm trying to bring everything in line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and painless save your data and install new. If you like an adventure read [How to extract and install .deb without the command dpkg?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282224/how-to-extract-and-install-deb-without-the-command-dpkg)

It is for Debian but should also work in Ubuntu.